# Запрет редактирования GET переменных

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, php7

Возник вопрос, есть ли способ запретить редактирования $_GET переменных в адресной строке браузера (к примеру при ручном корректировании чтобы выдавало ошибку), либо какой нибудь другой способ.

Comment: Нет способа запретить редактирование GET и даже POST-параметров. Доверять пришедшим от пользователя данным - плохая практика

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет способа запретить редактирование GET и даже POST-параметров. Доверять пришедшим от пользователя данным - плохая практика

Answer (score 0):

Можно отправлять их вместе с хеш-суммой, которую проверять. Можно и просто шифровать их.

Comment: А в чем проблема сгенерировать свою сумму?

Comment: Вопрос в том что если пользователь изменит get переменную, то сумма сгенерируется по тому же принципу